# How to print a vue table without breaking the table while changing the pages and have header and footer in every page?

Tags: vue.js, printing, vuejs3

I am trying to create a table ( nested table) and print it.link: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-jennings-6gblrw   ( click on print btn to understand problems.)

1- when printing it the table became broken when changing the page. I used the famous css: to avoid breaking but didn't work.

2-second problem is that the footer and header should repeat in each page.

3rd problem is in the nested table (col d e ) they should be exactly in the same line level but they appear different when one is bigger ( see d e column for the second row)

I would appreciate any help

code::

```
<template>
  <button @click="printTable">Print</button>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="printable-table">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="left">Name</div>
          <div class="right">Job Number</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="left">Address1</div>
          <div class="center">HEADER</div>
          <div class="right">Date</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="left">Address2</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="2">insID</th>
          <th rowspan="2">Location</th>
          <th rowspan="2">RT</th>
          <th colspan="3">D</th>
          <th colspan="2"> RS</th>
          <th rowspan="2">SN</th>
          <th colspan="3">S</th>
          <th rowspan="2">Comment</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th >DC</th>
          <th >DSC</th>
          <th>d</th>
          <th>rs</th>
          <th>CA</th>
          <th>ST</th>
          <th>SUA</th>
          <th>SA</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="row in data" v-bind:key="row.insID">
          <td>{{ row.insID }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.Location }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.RT }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.DC }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.DSC }}</td>
          <td v-if="typeof row.D === 'object'">
              <table>
                <tr v-for="(value, key) in row.D" v-bind:key="key">
                  <td>{{ key }}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td v-if="typeof row.D === 'object'">
              <table>
                <tr v-for="(value, key) in row.D" v-bind:key="key">
                  <td>{{ value }}</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          <td v-else>{{ row.D }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.CA }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.SN }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.ST }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.SUA }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.SA }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.Comment }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="13" class="footer">
          Footer - Page <span class="page-number"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>

    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  </div>
  
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      
      data: 
      
      [
    {
        "insID": "isnID1",
        "Location": "17918118",
        "RT": "selectif",
        "DC": "Structure",
        "DSC": "Frame",
        "D": {
            "Dent on face, ": "Box beam, ",
            "Rear post Twisted, ": "Boot 3x24, "
        },
        "CA": "replace",
        "SN": "1",
        "ST": "2 weeks",
        "SUA": "Put out of service",
        "SA": "Unload damaged levels before action time",
        "Comment": "Comment 1"
    },
    
    {
        "insID": "isnID2",
        "Location": "179181182",
        "RT": "selectif2",
        "DC": "Structure2",
        "DSC": "Frame2",
        "D": {
            "Dent on face2, ": "Box beam,2 ",
            "Rear post Twisted,2 ": "Boot 3x24, "
        },
        "CA": "replace2",
        "SN": "12",
        "ST": "2 weeks2",
        "SUA": "Put out of service2",
        "SA": "Unload damaged levels before action time2",
        "Comment": "Comment 12"
    },
    {
        "insID": "isnID3",
        "Location": "179181183",
        "RT": "selectif3",
        "DC": "Structure3",
        "DSC": "Frame3",
        "D": {
            "Dent on face3, ": "Box beam,sad3 ",
            "Rear post Twisted,3 ": "Boot 3x24, "
        },
        "CA": "replace3",
        "SN": "13",
        "ST": "2 weeks3",
        "SUA": "Put out of service3",
        "SA": "Unload damaged levels before action time3",
        "Comment": "Comment 13"
    },
    {
        "insID": "isnID4",
        "Location": "179181184",
        "RT": "selectif4",
        "DC": "Structure4",
        "DSC": "Frame4",
        "D": {
            "Dent on face4, ": "Box beam,4 ",
            "Rear post Twisted,4 ": "Boot 3x24, "
        },
        "CA": "replace4",
        "SN": "14",
        "ST": "2 weeks4",
        "SUA": "Put out of service4",
        "SA": "Unload damaged levels before action time4",
        "Comment": "Comment 14"
    },
    {
        "insID": "isnID5",
        "Location": "179181185",
        "RT": "selectif5",
        "DC": "Structure5",
        "DSC": "Frame5",
        "D": {
            "Dent on face5, ": "Box asdasd asdasd beam,5 ",
            "Rear post Twisted sad  asdasdasd asd dsa as d,5 ": "Boot 3x24, "
        },
        "CA": "replace5",
        "SN": "15",
        "ST": "2 weeks5",
        "SUA": "Put out of service5",
        "SA": "Unload damaged levels before action time5",
        "Comment": "Comment 15"
    },
    {
        "insID": "isnID6",
        "Location": "179181186",
        "RT": "selectif6",
        "DC": "Structure6",
        "DSC": "Frame6",
        "D": {
            "Dent on face6, ": "Box beam,6 ",
        },
        "CA": "replace6",
        "SN": "16",
        "ST": "2 weeks6",
        "SUA": "Put out of service6",
        "SA": "Unload damaged levels before action time6",
        "Comment": "Comment 16"
    },

    
]
     
    };
  },
  methods: {
    printTable() {
    this.updatePageNumbers();
    window.print();
  },
  updatePageNumbers() {
    const pageNumbers = document.querySelectorAll('.page-number');
    pageNumbers.forEach((pageNumber, index) => {
      pageNumber.textContent = index + 1;
    });
  },
}
};
</script>

<style>
table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 0.8rem; /* Adjust this value to make the text smaller or larger */
  line-height: 1.5;
}

th,
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 12px 8px;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

thead {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

thead th {
  position: relative;
}

thead th[colspan]::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

table table {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
}

table table td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

table table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header,
.footer {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.left,
.center,
.right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.left {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.right {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.row:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media print {
  /* hide header, footer, and URL */
  @page {
    size: auto;  /* use printer's default page size */
    margin: 0;   /* remove default page margins */
  }
  body {
    margin: 1.6cm; /* set a custom margin for the content area */
  }
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #printable-table,
  #printable-table * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #printable-table {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  table {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  tr {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
    -webkit-region-break-inside: avoid;
  }
  body {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
}
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
  table {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
  @page {
    margin-bottom: 50mm;
  }
</style>
```

I tried to add the media print part, but it didnt help. I added
`page-break-inside: avoid;`
but it didnt changed.
Also for repeating header and footer I dont know what to do. I need to have page number in footer and its showing wrong number now.

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-jennings-6gblrw